# create column in pyspark based on conditons

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am currently working with a spark dataframe having 7 columns and one column being date . In my case the date column is represented as Quarters i.e 2017Q1 , 2017Q2,2017Q3

How do i create 2 new columns as below

```
Date_String 
Replace 2017Q1 with string "January - March 2017" and
replace 2017Q2 with string "April -June 2017
```

I tried the below command

```
df= df.withColumn("Date_String",where(col("quarter_date") == "2017Q4"),lit('October - December 2017'))
```

Can anyone please help me on the above

Comment: Try replacing the `where` with `when` (assuming you already have imported `pyspark.sql.functions.when`)

Comment: Thanks @pault , Below is the solution to achieve it

Comment: df\
.withColumn('Date_String',when(df.quarter_date == "2017Q4",'October - December 2017')\
            .when(df.quarter_date == "2017Q2",'April - June 2017')\
            .when(df.quarter_date == "2017Q1",'January - March 2017')\
            .when(df.quarter_date == "2017Q3","July -September 2017")
            .otherwise('other'))\
.show()